# Changing property magnificationFilter in transform-only layer, will have no effect?

Tags: ios, layer

During transitions from view controllers (flip horizontal style) I received the following output in log:

<_UIFlippingLayer: 0x1453a8e0> - changing property magnificationFilter in transform-only layer, will have no effect

What is it about? Hot to fix it?

Comment: You should describe your problem more (at least some code) 'cause nobody can help you just with this.

Comment: I have the same warning when I use:
`layer.shouldRasterize = true`
`layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`

These layers look pixelated. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Lol. 2020 and no answers. Had this error in iPad Pro simulator and using Flip animation for segue changes. I found that changing to any other animation gives similar message too. So as of now, release :P